# why does nullptr not require header while nullptr_t does

Tags: c++, c++11

`nullptr_t` is the type for `nullptr`. When I use `nullptr_t`, I have to use the header file `<cstddef>` but why isn't it required when using the `nullptr` keyword alone?

Comment: The core language, which includes all the keywords, and the standard library, which includes its headers, make up a complete whole.  Parts of C++ are in the core language (e.g., `nullptr` or `int`), parts are in headers (e.g., `std::vector` or `std::string`), and parts straddle both (e..g., `typeid` and `<typeinfo>` for `std::type_info`; or `nullptr` and `<cstddef>` for `std::nullptr_t`).

Answer (score 5):

As per [[lex.key]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.key#1), `nullptr` is a keyword:

> The identifiers shown in Table 5 are reserved for use as keywords (that is, they are unconditionally treated as keywords in phase 7) [...]
>
> [[tab:lex.key]](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:lex.key): ... `nullptr`

Whereas `std::nullptr_t` is an alias declaration defined by the standard. Particularly, as of [[cstddef.syn]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstddef.syn), is is defined as the type of the a `nullptr` expression:

> #### Header `<cstddef>` synopsis
>
> ...
>
> ```
> using nullptr_t = decltype(nullptr);
> ```

as specified in [[support.types.nullptr]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.types.nullptr#1):

> The type `nullptr_­t` is a synonym for the type of a `nullptr` expression, and it has the characteristics described in [basic.fundamental] and [[conv.ptr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr).

Thus, to make use of `std::nullptr_t`, you need to include the `<cstddef>` header, but you can likewise use `decltype(nullptr)` if you simply want *the same underlying type* but without using the `std::nullptr_t` alias.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I would say it does answer the question, "When I use `nullptr_t`, I have to use the header file but why isn't it required when using the `nullptr` keyword alone"; namely pointing out that `nullptr_t` is an _alias declaration_ to the type of a `nullptr` expression, it is not the _type_ of `nullptr`; in the sense that it is needed to "declare" the keyword, which in itself would be a weird connotation. It does, however, indeed not provide the thorough background of your answer as to _why_ this design decision was made.

Answer (score 4):

`nullptr` is a keyword, `std::nullptr_t` is a type defined by the C++ Stadnard library. Keywords are not introduced by header files, they are "wired" in the compiler itself.

Comment: Extra "tip": One can use `using nullptr_t = decltype(nullptr);` without including any header.

Comment: Fun fact: that's basically how `std::nullptr_t` is defined.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Right: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/c%2B%2Bconfig#L284, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/__nullptr#L56.

Answer (score 4):

*Most* types defined by C++ are defined via the standard library. Only a handful — `char`, `int` … — are defined via keywords, and they are all old (i.e. they have been part of C++ since the beginning). Other types (`std::byte`, `std::initializer_list`, …) are not. There are many reasons for this, but mainly it just isn’t *necessary* to define new keywords, and defining new keywords is intrusive and breaks existing code that uses the same identifier, so it’s avoided when possible.

The real question therefore is: why did C++ define a keyword for `nullptr`? [The original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf) explicitly lists this as a design goal. It gives the following reasons, amongst others:

1. It doesn’t require including a header to use the value.
2. It makes it easier for compiler vendors to produce good error messages involving null pointers.
3. Implementing the `nullptr` value via C++ code in a header is challenging to make it work correctly in constant expressions. I believe that this point is no longer relevant since probably C++17, but it was definitely a concern in C++11, when the proposal was introduced.

Reason (1) on its own might not seem compelling, since the same reason would apply to the type name `nullptr_t`. But in actual usage, `nullptr` is a lot more common; code rarely needs to name the null pointer *type*.

Taken together, these are strong reasons to make the null pointer value constant a built-in keyword. But, as noted, the reasons for making the type name also keyword aren’t nearly as strong.